# Infinite quote escaping sequence

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence

*[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249908/extract-strings-from-text)*

We start with the string `a`, and forever append to the string a comma followed by the string quote-escaped, where quote-escaping means doubling all quotes in a string, and then surrounding it with an additional pair of quotes.

In the first few steps we will get:

- `a`
- `a,'a'`
- `a,'a','a,''a'''`
- `a,'a','a,''a''','a,''a'',''a,''''a'''''''`

If we continue to do that forever, we get the following infinite string:
`a,'a','a,''a''','a,''a'',''a,''''a''''''','a,''a'',''a,''''a'''''',''a,''''a'''',''''a,''''''''a''''''''''''''','a,''a'',''a,''''a'''''',''a,''''a'''',''''a,'''...`

If create a sequence, which is 1 at indices that string contains a quotes, we'll get the following sequence:

1. `0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...`

Alternatively, we can look at the indices of quotes, and get the following sequence (this is 0-indexed):

2. `2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 45, 46, ...`

Your task is to output one of these numeric sequences.

### Rules

- You can choose whether you use 0-indexing or 1-indexing.
- If you output sequence 1, you can use any truthy/falsey values instead of 1/0, or any two different consistent values.
- If you output sequence 2 (the one with the indices), you can choose if those indices use 0-indexing or 1-indexing.
- You can use one of following output modes:

  - Take \$n\$ as an input, and output the \$n\$-th element in the sequence.
  - Take \$n\$ as an input, and output all elements in the sequence up to the \$n\$-th element.
  - Take no input, and output the entire sequence forever.
- You can use any reasonable input/output format.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

This is code golf, so the shortest code wins.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 57 bytes (@Steffan)

```
a=b="/"
while[print(end=b)]:b="/\%s\\"%repr(a)[1:-1];a+=b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LRNtk2yV9JW4yjMyc1KjC4oy80o0UvNSbJM0Y61AMjGqxTExSqpFqQVFGoma0YZWuoax1onatkkQA6DmwMwDAA)

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 58 bytes

```
a=b="/"
while[print(end=b)]:b="/\\%s\\"%repr(a)[1:-1];a+=b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rRJtk2yV9JW4yjMyc1KjC4oy80o0UvNSbJM0Y61AMjExqsUxMUqqRakFRRqJmtGGVrqGsdaJ2rZJEBOgBsEMBAA)

Prints the entire sequence using `/` for `0` and `\` for `1`.

Comment: Smart abuse of the behavior of `repr` on backslashes

Comment: You don't need to escape the backslash in `\\%s` for -1 byte

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>22</sup> 19 bytes

```
{1&(],1,~0 1,+#])&0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/qw3VNGJ1DHXqDBQMdbSVYzXVDP5rcqUmZ@QrpClpK2TqGZpDeIbmCtV6CgY6IGSIQUIYhkgM/LLIDGQthhhcKpj2HwA)

*-3 thanks to ovs!*

Quite slow, as we iterate n times and take the nth result.

TIO link shows first 17 terms.

Approach is straightforward recursion:

- `{` nth item (0-indexed) from...
- `1&(              )&0` Iterate n times, starting with 0, and using a constant left arg of 1...
- `(],1,~0 1,+#])` Bookend `+#]` (to be explained below) with `0 1` and  `1`
- `+#]` The only interesting part, really.  This is how we double up the quotes.  Consider `0 0 1 0 1`:

  - `+` adds 1 to every element, taking advantage of the fixed left arg of 1:

    ```
    1 1 2 1 2
    ```
  - `#]` use that as a duplication mask for `0 0 1 0 1`:

    ```
    0 0 1 1 0 1 1
    ```

Comment: `{.1&(],1,~0 1,+#])&0` is 20 bytes, and can you do `{` instead of `{.` for the *n-th* value output format?

Comment: @ovs, I really like the idea of reusing the fixed left arg of 1 to save a but for `>:`!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
0w?(:k≈$vß"1Wf)Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIwdz8oOmviiYgkdsOfXCIxV2Yp4bqOIiwiIiwiMTUiXQ==)

Same idea as the Jelly answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 57 bytes

```
.\n0\;.n e*.n `t
dup \; `' `flat1`,0`,1`+ `+
dup \; e&
1,
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin) Returns an iterable with the first *n* elements.

The code above extremely inefficiently runs through *n* iterations. For testing purposes, the following code is equivalent:

```
100 ; `_
.\n0;.n `t
dup \; `' `flat1`,0`,1`+ `+ `size.n < \@ e&
dup \; e&
1,
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
.\n 0 \; .n e* .n `t
dup ( dup ( 1, ) e& ) `' `flat 1`, 0`, 1`+ `+
```

- `.\n 0 \; .n e*` store the input as *n*, push 0, execute the next line *n* times...

  - `` dup ( dup ( 1, ) e& ) `' `flat `` top of stack with 1s replaced with `1 1`
  - `` 1`, 0`, 1`+ `+ `` prepend `0 1`, append `1`, append result to existing sequence

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 43 bytes

```
f n=iterate(\x->x++'b':show x)"a"!!n!!n<'a'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuxNu9zEzDwFW4WC0pLgkiIFFYWUfIVMBRtdhWgDPT1DA4NYa4XMNIU0oFhJRmqegpKhjoKSQmpOcaqCkgGQubS0JE3X4qZ2mkKebWZJalFiSapGTIWuXYW2tnqSulVxRn65QoWmUqKSomIeENmoJ6pDtCyAUlAaAA)

`f n` is the `n`th element of sequence #1, as either True or False.

The string built by `iterate` has the same "shape" as the real string:

```
ab"a"b"ab\"a\""b"ab\"a\"b\"ab\\\"a\\\"\""…
a,'a','a,''a''','a,''a'',''a,''''a'''''''…
```

`"\` both correspond to quotes, `ab` correspond to `a,`. So, we can use `char<'a'` to detect quotes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
0;x‘Ø1jƲŻ$$¡ḣ
```

A monadic Link that accepts `n` and yields the first `n` terms of the boolean is-a-quote sequence.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//MDt44oCYw5gxasayxbskJMKh4bij////MTI)** Or see a longer prefix (by not heading) [here](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//MDt44oCYw5gxasayxbskJMKh////NA).

#### How?

Starts with a zero (the initial `a`) and builds up the sequence exactly as described in the question, using zeros for non-quotes and ones for quotes.

```
0;x‘Ø1jƲŻ$$¡ḣ - Link: integer, n
0             - set the left argument, x, to zero
           ¡  - repeat n times:
          $   -   last two links as a monad - f(x):
         $    -     last two links as a monad - g(x):
       Ʋ      -       last four links as a monad - h(x):   e.g. [0,0,1,0,1]
   ‘          -         increment                               [1,1,2,1,2]
  x           -         repeat (double the quotes)              [0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
    Ø1        -         [1,1]
      j       -         join (wrap in quotes)                   [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]
        Ż     -       prepend a zero (prepend a comma)          [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]
 ;            -     concatenate that to x
            ḣ - head to index n
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
;Ø.;x‘$;1
0Ç¡ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//O8OYLjt44oCYJDsxCjDDh8Kh4bij////MTU)

Full program yielding first \$n\$ elements of the quote/non-quote sequence. Exponentially slow; better tested with [manual control of the number of iterations](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//O8OYLjt44oCYJDsxCjDDh8aTwqHhuKP//zf/NjE).

```
;Ø.;x‘$;1    Monadic helper link: iterate
;Ø.          Append [0, 1].
   ;         Append
    x $      the argument with its elements repeated by
     ‘       themselves incremented.
       ;1    Append 1.

0Ç¡ḣ    Main link
 Ç¡     Repeat that n times
0       starting from 0,
   ḣ    and take the first n elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Batch Script, 80 bytes

Outputs the first n elements of sequence 1,

```
CMD/VON/CSET s=0^&(FOR /L %%Q in (1,1,8)DO @SET s=!s!01!s:1=11!1)^&ECHO !s:~,%1!
```

so ie if file is called quote.bat

```
CALL quote.bat 5
```

gives you

```
00101
```

I hardcoded 8 iterations because that's the maximum amount before the string gets too big and CMD fails to parse it. So I'm not too sure if this answer counts, but I thought it would be neat to post it anyway.

Edit : minus a bunch of bytes thanks to Neil

Comment: I'm not sure `p` is necessary, is it? (Also, I tried 9 iterations and CMD simply crashed on me. Oops.)

Comment: Ahhhh thanks, that was big oversight on my part lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>109</s>, <s>71</s>, <s>64</s>, <s>63</s>, 62 bytes

```python
a=w='0'
while[print(end=w)]:w=f"01{a.replace('1','11')}1";a+=w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9G23FbdQJ2rPCMzJzW6oCgzr0QjNS/Ftlwz1qrcNk3JwLA6Ua8otSAnMTlVQ91QXUfd0FBds9ZQyTpR27b8/38A)

-45 thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

-1 because of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250015/infinite-quote-escaping-sequence/250023#250023)

-1 thanks to [@AnttiP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84290/anttip)

### Explanation (Outdated):

```python
a=w="0"
```

Self-explanatory

```python
while 1:
```

Repeat infinite times.

```python
print(end=w+"0");
```

print w with 0. There's "0" because "0" is a comma.

```python
w="1"+
```

w is "1" and...

```python
a.replace("1","11")+
```

double the ones of a and...

```python
"1";
```

one.

```python
a="00"+w
```

Put two zeroes and w.

Comment: Why not just use raw `0` and `1` instead of using `a'` and replacing them? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9G23FbJQImrPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCM1L8W2XBsormkNlDZU0k7UK0otyElMTtUA8nSUDA2VNLWBLOtEoGYDJe3y//8B "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: This actually doesn't produce correct output. [64 bytes that does](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8K22FbdQJ2rPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCM1L8W2WNMaJGWorl2hV5RakJOYnKqhbqiuo25oqK6pDWRZV2jbFv//DwA), though

Comment: Use a format string to save a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9G23FbdQJ2rPCMzJzW6oCgzr0QjNS/Ftlwz1qrcNk3JwLA6Ua8otSAnMTlVQ91QXUfd0FBds9ZQyTpR27b8/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>52</s> 47 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,r=?0{r[n]||f[n,r+"01#{r.gsub ?1,'11'}1"]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5Pp8jW3qC6KDovtqYmLRrI1VYyMFSuLtJLLy5NUrA31FE3NFSvNVSKrf1foKBhoKdnaGCgqZebWKChlqapZa/zHwA)

Returns the nth element.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔0ηＷ›θＬη≔⁺⁺η0⪫11⪫⪪η1¦11η…ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LCsMgEEX3/Qpx5YCFuM6qZFFaSgn0C6xIRrBqfLT066022QwznDP3KpRReWlrvbhQ8r28njqyFcbDKSWzOEYHygm2@4PGasLOUcvcFU5u2i0ZGQIA2e3ZlrQN5KS9AidXb1qKEHRfH8Ga/Mei405awNYxR@Mym77K6gl96NYKMNYqhnp82x8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` elements of sequence 1. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔0η
```

Start with a string of `0` instead of `a`.

```
Ｗ›θＬψ
```

Repeat until there are enough elements.

```
≔⁺⁺η0⪫11⪫⪪η1¦11η
```

Extend the string by appending its quotation, but use `0` instead of a comma and `1` instead of a quote.

```
…ηθ
```

Output the first `n` elements.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>50</s>  49 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

Returns the \$n\$-th term of the binary sequence, 0-indexed, where `0`'s are encoded with `2`'s.

```javascript
f=(n,s='2')=>s[n]||f(n,s+21+s.replace(/1/g,11)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEADAr3hzF@2mBno0kHeEUMSakGBX0VIo5O8mvc5hdvd11Zctf26cXqG1xQLramUv0Q514vk4lr@o3qhKJeTofIDOdKs2BpXB5hPXFAPFtMJERGMp7gePO870dhngqQWjsIO4HkTa08YgtZCI7QQ)

Comment: By applying the "any two different consistent values" rule, you can use other number instead of `0` to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÎFDX3:5šbJÀ«I£
```

Outputs the first \$n\$ items of the binary sequence as string.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cJ@bS4SxlenRhUlehxsOrfY8tPj/f0MDAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Î              # Push 0 and the input
 F             # Pop and loop the input amount of times:
  D            #  Duplicate the current string
   X3:         #  Replace all 1 with 3
      5š       #  Convert the string to a list of digits, and prepend a 5
        b      #  Convert each digit to a binary string
               #  (3 become 11; 5 becomes 101; 0 and 1 remain unchanged)
         J     #  Join it back together to a single string
          À    #  Rotate it once towards the right, so the leading 1 is trailing
           «   #  Append it to the previous string we've duplicated
            I£ #  Only leave the first input amount of characters
               # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 61 bytes

```bash
for((a=0;${#a}<=$1;));do a+=01${a//1/11}1;done;echo ${a:$1:1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDBaoQwEL37FUOaQ0QWTemhu9m0hW2/YvWQxhFDiy6agiD5djtaLR56aWDe5D3ehMl7N309VV@N9a5toBIxjFPVdkIYnSk@3plw1lyqOFZlCybRmeSjSVOZShkkaQ0qtHULpJ64PMkwhahE@2k6hIMBHG5oPZZaZJCB3NWMcsW/tA03h9zd/jUT7/exNdoP7LRg@fB2nw/HC9UDg42@5sPjhcURRQBCgKMQwJ0ZBbH95PpSBKYgSdySSQR0vCaHC2whOJNfN3fFqveaiwoY9/T8MoS9J9oz0Jo6/rhunWv8YoPDE/Cegl13vvLnIuQNi@bQp28)

Returns the \$0\$-based \$n^{\text{th}}\$ element of the binary sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 57 bytes

```
s>>=id
s=[0]:[0:1:[b|b<-a,c<-[0..b]]++[1]|a<-scanl1(++)s]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuzu3MTMPAVbhYKizLwSBRWFksTsVAVDAwMgM2ZpaUmarsVNy2I7O9vMFK5i22iDWKtoAytDq-ikmiQb3USdZBvdaAM9vaTYWG3taMPYmkQb3eLkxLwcQw1tbc3iWIgBC6AUlAYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 27 bytes

```apl
{{∊⍵0 1(,⍨¨@(⍸⍵)⊢⍵)1}⍣⍵⊢,0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v7r6UUfXo96tBgqGGjqPelccWuGg8ah3B1BE81HXIhBlWPuodzGQAeTqGNT@f9Q39VHbBFK1Gf8HAA)

Comment: Hey, welcome back to PPCG! Btw converting this to a tradfn saves some bytes. Besides, I think porting Jonah's solution would be shorter.